# MobileAds.initialize() must be called prior to getting version string

Tags: android, admob

I am recently getting more crashes from Admob version 17.2.0 which is also set up with mediation . This issue is happening currently which was not happening before with the same dependency . According to fabric crashlytics `The issue was first seen July 12, 2019 and there was a spike in activity starting about an hour ago.`

This is happening because of bug in facebook mediation adapter 5.3.0 . It can be fixed by updating to version 5.4.0 but it will take time every user to update their App .  Admob team please fix it soon as possible .

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MobileAds.initialize() must be called prior to getting version string.
           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java)
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabc.getVersionString(zzabc.java)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(MobileAds.java)
```

MainActivity.kt oncreate method first line:-

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "id")
```

Android Manifest inside Application tag:-

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="id" />
```

Update:-
I think i am not alone many devs are facing same issue today

Links:-

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/17NwIkYauBE
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/kDjdr53hO8o

Update:-
Please do something fast now getting more & more crashes already almost 4000 crashes (5% of users) today only .

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried? Manifest file and the Java code(where you use the adview)

Comment: added it, i am almost sure its not because of android code as there were no crash before 2 days in the same app same version.

Comment: also getting this crash from yesterday more than 2000 users effected

Comment: Found this link about this issue here, may need to  go ahead and update facebook adapter to address the issue. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-mediation/issues/133

Comment: Yes it will solve it , but it was working well before 12 July and now its crashing too much how did this happen ? .
 Also many users will remain to this version of App even after updating it and will keep getting crashes if anyone not solves it .